# App icon does not appear on upgrade under Settings>Printing

Tags: android, android-icons, android-print-framework

We are working on Print service(plugin) related application, we have a production version which is available on Google Play. We planned to release an updated version of this app with the new app icon(launcher icon). We replaced existing res/drawable/ic_launcher.png with a newer icon with a different name like res/drawable/ic_new_launcher.png. So to see the updated new logo, We have to navigate Android Device setting -> Printing. It is showing me the Android logo instead of Our app logo.
We can see app icon only if we restart device & coming back to Printing service screen under device setting.
We tried to move ic_new_launcher.png from drawable to mipmap but still facing the same issue.

Issue observed on Samsung Galaxy S8 plus(7.0 Nougat) & LG G6(7.0 Nougat). Not sure this issue resides on other device models & OS version.

Note: *App logo is showing perfectly if we install freshly
Attached Image for reference

Please let me know If any other information required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your launcher icon in all below res folder i hope its help

1)mipmap-hdpi

2)mipmap-mdpi

3)mipmap-xhdpi

4)mipmap-xxhdpi

5)mipmap-xxxhdpi

Comment: Make sure that the Intent of your Launcher Activity is named MAIN i.e,

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />        </intent-filter>

Comment: It is a print service plugin application. There will not be any launcher activity for it